# How to calculate punctuality in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two times : actual_arr and sched_arr. Both times are in the format char (YYYYMMDDHH24MISS).

Now I've to calculate the punctuality of each movement. The rows are stored as below :

MovtName            Actual_Arr            Sched_Arr

```
 mvt1         20140206215900      20140206210000
```

Now my definition of punctuality is (in percentage) : (actual time - sched time)/sched time*100.

I know how to calculate the difference for each movement. The code snippet I used is :

```
Trunc((To_Date(actual_arr,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')-To_Date(sched_arr,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))*24*60,2)
```

This gives the delay in minutes.

Now what do I divide this value with? This is what I cannot wrap my head around. How do I convert the sched_arr into minutes? Or in other words what is the valid denominator for the equation for punctuality?

If anybody has a more correct definition for punctuality and how to calculate it, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your definition of punctuality makes no sense. Percentage of a date is a meaningless measure, because the zero point can be defined as any arbitrary point in time. Am I more punctual if I am 10 minutes late for an 11 o'clock appointment as opposed to when I am 10 minutes late for a 1 o'clock appointment? By your measure, I will be.

Comment: You need the "departure" time or scheduled duration.  Is that available?  Your formula should be something like (actual time - sched time)/(expected duration).

Answer (score 0):

For a single meeting, just use the lateness in minutes as a measurement of punctuality.

When you have multiple meetings you can start to define punctuality in non-dimensional terms, such as the percentage of meetings which started more then five minutes late.